# Working in excel calculating age between a date range

Tags: excel

Please help

Using excel i am trying to calculate the age of an athlete in specific date range or season, which would then classify them within an age group.  Athletes age has been calculated using datediff method.
Can i specify a table column to operate within a date range?
would if functions or v lookup be of use?

Any help greatly received

thanks

Peter

Comment: You talk about table but give no example of the setup.  DateDiff is the way to go.  Not sure what you want from us.  It is hard to even give an opinion without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup with the last parameter as true or 1, to get an approximate match, e.g.

```
Age     Age Group
0          0-10
10        10-20
20        20-40
40        40+
```

and set your formula as

```
=vlookup (d5,$a$2:$b5,2,1)
```